# Sum up all values in a column, except for rows with a checked box in another column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've got the following data:

[image: Google Sheets data]

And beneath the last visible cell on column `C`, I want to sum up all values in the cells, but only if their corresponding value on column `B` (the "Taxed" checkbox) is set to false.

I tried this formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(QUERY(B2:C11, "WHERE B = FALSE" , 1), , 2))
```

But it doesn't work well. It gives me **$169.30**, but it should be **$115.23**.

Is there any way I could fix my formula, or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a much simpler `SUMIF` formula:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B11,FALSE,C2:C11)
```

Please read about the [`SUMIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583) function.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thanks so much, @marikamitsos! I was away, otherwise I would've accepted the answer faster :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. :)